# Sound won't play after I load a level

Tags: c#, audio, xna, xna-4.0

If I just tell the song to play throughout the opening Menu & 1st Level (ie, always so far) then it plays just fine. However, I want the sound only to play when the player presses enter and level 1 loads up.

Relevant code is here:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    // Opening Screen Textures
    test = Content.Load<Texture2D>("test");

    // Load sounds here
    if (gameState == GameState.Level1)
    {
        backgroundSong = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Call to Adventure");
        SoundEffectInstance backgroundSongInstance = backgroundSong.CreateInstance();
        backgroundSongInstance.IsLooped = true;
        backgroundSong.Play();
    }
}
```

So like I said, before I made the if loop, the sound played just fine. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The game goes from `gameState.Menu` to `gameState.Level1` when user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> (graphics load up and apart from sound everything behaves).

Full code is here in case I missed anything above:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

    // game state
    GameState gameState = GameState.OpeningMenu;

    // menu fields
    Texture2D test;

    // Level 1 textures list
    Texture2D skyBackground;
    //Texture2D dirtTexture;
    Texture2D grassTexture;
    Texture2D leftGrassTexture;
    Texture2D rightGrassTexture;

    // sounds
    SoundEffect backgroundSong;

    // Level 1 platforms
    Platforms platform1;
    Platforms platform2;
    Platforms platform3;
    Platforms platform4;
    Platforms platform5;
    Platforms platform6;
    Platforms platform7;
    Platforms platform8;
    Platforms platform9;

    // drawing variables
    int oneWidthUnit = WINDOW_WIDTH / 40;
    int oneHeightUnit = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 30;
    //int twoWidthUnits = WINDOW_WIDTH / 20;
    //int twoHeightUnits = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 15;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = WINDOW_WIDTH;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Window.Title = "Rory's Super Mega Awesome Game of Awesomeness";
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // Opening Screen Textures
        test = Content.Load<Texture2D>("test");

        // Load sounds here
        if (gameState == GameState.Play)
        {
            backgroundSong = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Call to Adventure");
            SoundEffectInstance backgroundSongInstance = backgroundSong.CreateInstance();
            backgroundSongInstance.IsLooped = true;
            backgroundSong.Play();
        }

        // Load Level 1 sprite textures here
        skyBackground = Content.Load<Texture2D>("skybackground");
        //dirtTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("dirt");
        grassTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("grass_top");
        leftGrassTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("edge_left");
        rightGrassTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("edge_right");

        //create platforms
        platform1 = new Platforms(0, 28 * oneHeightUnit, 15, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);
        platform2 = new Platforms(26 * oneWidthUnit, 28 * oneHeightUnit, 14, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);
        platform3 = new Platforms(10 * oneWidthUnit, 23 * oneHeightUnit, 7, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);
        platform4 = new Platforms(18 * oneWidthUnit, 19 * oneHeightUnit, 5, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);
        platform5 = new Platforms(5 * oneWidthUnit, 15 * oneHeightUnit, 9, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);
        platform6 = new Platforms(19 * oneWidthUnit, 11 * oneHeightUnit, 3, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);
        platform7 = new Platforms(23 * oneWidthUnit, 7 * oneHeightUnit, 3, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);
        platform8 = new Platforms(30 * oneWidthUnit, 7 * oneHeightUnit, 7, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);
        platform9 = new Platforms(34 * oneWidthUnit, 14 * oneHeightUnit, 6, grassTexture, leftGrassTexture, rightGrassTexture);

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // goes from menu to level 1 when player presses enter
        if (gameState == GameState.OpeningMenu && Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
        {
            gameState = GameState.Play;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        // draw opening menu
        if (gameState == GameState.OpeningMenu)
        {
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            spriteBatch.Draw(test, rec, Color.White);
        }

        // draw level 1
        else if (gameState == GameState.Play)
        {
            DrawScenery();

            platform1.Draw(spriteBatch);
            platform2.Draw(spriteBatch);
            platform3.Draw(spriteBatch);
            platform4.Draw(spriteBatch);
            platform5.Draw(spriteBatch);
            platform6.Draw(spriteBatch);
            platform7.Draw(spriteBatch);
            platform8.Draw(spriteBatch);
            platform9.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    #region Drawing Code

    // draw the sky
    private void DrawScenery()
    {
        Rectangle backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        spriteBatch.Draw(skyBackground, backgroundRectangle, Color.White);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LoadContent` is normally called once, to load your content, while `Update()` is called about 60 times per second (depends). You code for detecting the jump is fine, and it looks like you would expect the code in `LoadContent` to be executed when you change game states. This is not the case, the code has no way in knowing you want to do this (you could make an event handler). You should probably create a method like `PlaySounds()`, and (previously) you would call it as you load the game/level. Now you will call it when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You should also just go ahead and load all your needed content, since you won't be returning to `LoadContent()` again.

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    // Opening Screen Textures
    test = Content.Load<Texture2D>("test");

    //LOAD but DONT PLAY sound
    backgroundSong = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Call to Adventure");
    backgroundSongInstance = backgroundSong.CreateInstance();
    backgroundSongInstance.IsLooped = true;

    //Rest of code cut out for example!
}
```

Go ahead and make `SoundEffectInstance backgroundSongInstance` a new variable, just so you have more control over it (since it will be destroyed as it exits the scope of the `Update()` method, so we can access it later.

In your `Update` method:

```
 //Goes from menu to level 1 when player presses enter
 if (gameState == GameState.OpeningMenu && Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
 {
      gameState = GameState.Play;
      //Start playing sound
      backgroundSongInstance.Play();
 }
```

Comment: TIL LoadContent is only called once during the game. This is why I love this site, I come away learning much more than I expected to learn. Thanks for the help, upvote and correct answer awarded!